# Testing a buffered reader reading from input stream

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I have problems when testing my code. I think that the problem has to do with using a BufferedReader reading from an InputStreamReader.
I used IntelliJ and give the following input:

```
Hello
World!
```

Why is my program not printing anything? Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Deque<String> lines = new ArrayDeque<>();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        lines.push(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }

    while (!lines.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(lines.pop());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code stunk in the first loop.

To fix this, just modify your loop condition to be the next:

```
while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
    lines.push(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Then your loop will exit when you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Or you can add any other `exit code`. Such as `while (line != null && !line.equals("exit"))`. So when you enter in the console your `exit code`(`exit` in the example above) your loop will stop and you will get your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting stuck in an infinite loop because the following condition never evaluates to false:

```
while (line != null) {
  lines.push(line);
  line = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to know when you are done providing input. On *Ubuntu* I had to input:

```
Hello
World
```

Than I did hit <kbd>Strg + D</kbd> to signal *EOS*. Afterwards I got the output:

```
Hello
World
```